# Returning false from ASP MVC Filter by default Redirecting to Account Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

I need to check every time before browsing that if a certain session is set or not. If session is set then will permit user to his/her desired page. Else redirect him to the session setup Controller & Action. For the shake I did the belowed task. But I can find way to redirect from filter. It is redirecting to Account Controller when returning false from the custom filter. I will really appreciate him who will help me.

In my Global.asax.cs I coded this:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     ......
     ......
     RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
 }

 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
 { 
     filters.Add(new CustomFilters()); 
 }
```

And then I added the bellowed code in my Filter/CustomFilters.cs directory.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly|AttributeTargets.Class| AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomFilters : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["HamdunSoft"] == "HamdunSoft")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false; //I need to redirect to my custom Controller/Action. But from here
                         it is redirecting  Account Controller default.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302; httpContext.Response.RedirectLocation= "your custom Controller/Action"; httpContext.Response.End();`

Comment: Thanks, But can you also tell me when returning false where the code control goes. Means where is the redirecting code for Account Controller :) ? @KhanhTO

Comment: when you `return false`, it just exits the code of `CustomFilters`, but the flow continues. The redirecting code is all the code I showed you, it really stops the current request processing and sends a http 302 redirect to the browser which sends another request and restart the flow

Answer (score 0):

You need to override HandleUnauthorizedRequest function also so you can redirect to the desired location:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (httpContext.Session["HamdunSoft"] != "HamdunSoft")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new{ controller = "YourCustomController", action = "YourCustomAction" }));
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new{ controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
```